# Getting Row Index for LINQ Query using Custom Object

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query to receive indexes:

```
fieldIndexes = this.record.Fields.Where(a => !a.IsCodeField)
                                 .OrderBy(a => a.DatabaseIndex)
                                 .Select(a => a.DatabaseIndex - 1)
                                 .ToArray();
```

But I want to replace the `a.DatabaseIndex` with the actual index of the search. I am aware of the syntax `.Select((a, index) => new (index, a))...` but I am not sure how to cast the `a` here to be of my type which in this case is `Field`. I have tried:

```
fieldIndexes = this.record.Fields.Select((a, index) => new {index, a})
                                 .Where(a => !a.IsCodeField) // <- Invalid Cast. 
                                 .OrderBy(a => a.DatabaseIndex)
                                 .Select(a => a.DatabaseIndex - 1)
                                 .ToArray();
```

How can I cast `a` to my type within the LINQ statement?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Where` clause you are working with your newly created anonymous objects with properties `a` and `index`, which you can use:

```
.Where(a => !a.a.IsCodeField)
```

Of course this can be done in more readable fasion:

```
fieldIndexes = this.record.Fields.Select((a, index) => new {Index = index, Field = a})
                                 .Where(a => !a.Field.IsCodeField)
                                 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You are projecting sequence items to anonymous objects with properties `index` and `a`. Original item will be accessible via property `a`:

```
fieldIndexes = this.record.Fields.Select((a, index) => new {index, a})
                                 .Where(x => !x.a.IsCodeField)
```